# Explain this docker run command?

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker. I follow this tutorial [Compose and ASP.NET Core with SQL Server](https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/) and I'm having difficulty understanding this command.

```
docker run -v ${PWD}:/app --workdir /app microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs for `docker run`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, If one of the answers to your question is correct you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
u can read more on this https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Answer (score 0):

- `-v` Means mount a directory from the host inside the container.
- `-v ${PWD}:/app` Means mount current directory in your machine to `/app` directory in the container.
- `--workdir /app` Means set container workdir to the `/app` directory.
- `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk` The docker image to run.
- `dotnet new mvc --auth Individual` the command to run inside the container (since workdir is set to `/app` this command will run from `/app` directory ).

`$PWD` Is a shell variable that contain the path to current directory changing dynamically according to the current directory.

Hope this will help.